# how to count words in p tag in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to count words in few paragraphs in javascript. How i call to my javascript function?

```
<html>
    <head></head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function cnt() {
            var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

            for(var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
                alert(paragraphs[i].innerHTML);
            }
        }
    </script>

    <body>
        <p>some text</p>
        <p>some text</p>
        <p>text text text</p>
</html>
```

Comment: Split them on the spaces and count the length?

Comment: `.innerHTML` is going to fetch any html inside the tags as well. you probably want `.innerText`, which would fetch ONLY the visible/readable text and ignore tags.

Comment: Define “word”. Is “tax-free” one word or two? How about “日本国”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
function cnt(){
    var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++)
    {
        count += paragraphs[i].innerHTML.split(' ').length;
    }
}
```

Please try the following snippet:

```js
// I changed the name of function, in order to be more meaningfull.
function countWords(){
  
    // Select all the p elements in the page.
    var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  
    // The counter.
    var count = 0;
  
    for(var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++)
    {
        // Split the innerHtml of the current paragraph to count the words.
        count += paragraphs[i].innerHTML.split(' ').length;
    }
   
    document.write("Number of words: "+count);
}

countWords();
```

```html
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>text text text</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Split on spacing, and use the resulting array's `length`:

```
function wordCount(elements) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        count += elements[i].textContent.split(/\s/).length;
    }
    return count;
}
var wordsInParagraphs = wordCount(document.getElementsByTagName("p"));
```

Comment: Use `.textContent` rather than `.innerText`. Firefox doesn't have `.innerText`.